# Copying data from one excel file to another - Subscript out of range

Tags: excel

I have below code where I am trying to copy the excel file data into different excel file but I get an error: **Run-time error '9' Subscript out of range**

```
Sub Button1_Click()
Dim directory As String, fileName As String, sheet As Worksheet, total As Integer
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Application.DisplayAlerts = False

directory = "\\test\CheckFile"
fileName = "test2.xlsx"

Do While fileName <> ""
Workbooks.Open (fileName)
For Each sheet In Workbooks(fileName).Worksheets
 total = Workbooks("Book1.xlt").Worksheets.Count
 Workbooks(fileName).Worksheets(sheet.Name).Copy _  //error appears here
 after:=Workbooks("Book1.xlt").Worksheets(total)
Next sheet

Workbooks(fileName).Close
fileName = Dir()
Loop

Application.ScreenUpdating = True
Application.DisplayAlerts = True

End Sub
```

Comment: On what line is the code erroring out on? Can you provide the exact error message?

Comment: I have added exact error message and highlighted where the error appears **//error appears here**

Answer (score 0):

OK, I've redone my answer to account for your latest information. I created this folder: `C:\test\CheckFile`. Inside there are two excel files both saved as .xlsx. I created an empty PAY.xlsm and saved it somewhere else (ie. Not in the test\CheckFile directory). I had PAY.xlsm open before running the code.

I think the template files .xlt cause problems. They open up with a different name. When `Workbooks.Open (fileName)` goes to open Book2.xlt, it opens up as Book21.xlsx. That then leads to the subscript out of range error.

Then I ran this code and it worked:

```
Sub Button1_Click()
    Dim directory As String, fileName As String, sheet As Worksheet, total As Integer

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Application.DisplayAlerts = False

    directory = "C:\test\checkfile\"
    fileName = Dir(directory)

    Do While fileName <> ""
        Workbooks.Open (fileName)

        For Each sheet In Workbooks(fileName).Worksheets
             total = Workbooks("PAY.xlsm").Worksheets.Count

              Workbooks(fileName).Worksheets(sheet.Name).Copy _
             after:=Workbooks("PAY.xlsm").Worksheets(total)
        Next sheet
        Workbooks(fileName).Close
        fileName = Dir()
    Loop

    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    Application.DisplayAlerts = True


End Sub
```

Comment: I see what you mean.  My answer involved an issue with the Dir() function, that hasn't been hit yet. I just ran your code and got the Subscript out of range error on `total = Workbooks("Book1.xlt").Worksheets.Count`. I was able to get past it by ensuring that Book1.xlt was open.

Comment: Also I found that if you double click a file with .xlt to open it, it will open with a "1" appended to the name.  Ex. Book1.xlt will open as Book11.xlt